# Convergence and non-convergence of operators on a hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{e_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis of a hilbert space $H$ and let $T_n:H\to H$ and $T:H\to H$ be given by 
$$T_n(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1{j}\langle x,e_j\rangle e_j\ \ T(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n}\langle x, e_n\rangle e_n$$
Then, is it true that $\|T_n-T\|$ does not converge to zero but $\forall x\in H$, $\|T_n(x)-T(x)\|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$?

I think that both the operator and the image converge, because the definition of the operators seems same to me and partial sums of convergent series is convergent to the sum in a complete space. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Your intuition is the natural one. However, this example is specifically tailored to challenge such a naive intuition. Reason carefully on the definition of operator norm.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I think the main fact is that $\sup$ is not attained in the space. But could you elaborate as to when the $\sup$ would be attained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x \in H$ we have
$$
\|T_n(x)-T(x)\|^2
= \Big\|\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty}\frac1{j}\langle x,e_j\rangle e_j \Big\|^2
= \sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j^2}|\langle x,e_j\rangle |^2
\leq \Big(\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j^2} \Big) \|x\|^2,$$

Hence, $\|T_n-T\| \leq \big(\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j^2}\big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.
Since $ \big(\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j^2}\big)^{\frac{1}{2}} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, we derive $\|T_n-T\| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.